# Accessing bonus campaigns in L4D game of the year edition

Tags: xbox-360, left-4-dead

I have the L4D game of the year edition and I understand there are 3 new campaigns that are on the disc.  When I played through with a friend I did not see an option to play Crash Course, The Sacrifice or The Last Stand.  Are these only available in single player?  Do I have to do something in the game to unlock the extra campaigns?

Sorry Xbox 360 edition.

Comment: AFAIK steam automatically downloads the bonus campaigns, are you online with steam or are you playing offline?

Comment: It might help to add what platform you're playing on. PC, 360...?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I am on the Xbox.  I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Game of the Year" edition of Left4Dead is a bit confusing, and you might call it an outright misnomer.

If we're talking about the [Xbox 360 edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0025KZV7A), it comes with just the Survival mode, which was *free DLC anyhow* - but it's on the disc, as opposed to something you've got to download from Xbox Live.  If you want the other campaigns, Crash Course and The Sacrifice, you're going to have to [pony up 560 Microsoft points (~$7) **each**](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Left-4-Dead/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d80245410830) (or wait for a sale/price drop sometime in the future)

If you're talking about the [PC edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/500/), it comes with all the DLC campaigns, but again, that was *free DLC for PC users*.  You'll get everything via Steam when you install it.

Effectively there's very little difference between the "Standard" and "Game of the Year" editions on both platforms.

Comment: and yet another reason to avoid xbox...   Every time Valve puts the entire PC L4D/L4D2 package on sale for less than the price of one of the XBox DLCs, a part of me gets happier :)

Comment: I like to play with my wife, and she's more of the console gamer type.  Getting her in front of the xbox is hard enough, and PC's a non-starter.  It does *suck* though, and I wish the GOTY edition came with all the DLC. :(

Comment: @agent86 hand her an xbox controller connected to a PC.

Comment: @ColinD - Better yet, [enable splitscreen](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=745113) on your PC, and connect it to your TV. that way, nothing's changed

Comment: Uhh thats actually incorrect it would still be a change because your just assuming said pc runs the same as said xbox and is equally reactive plus pc can have other programs cause you to unintentionally exit the game or various other things via prompts that someone in a place of danger iin game doesnt have time to deal with so consoles are easier for any person to start with